# How to toggle fullscreen mode?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my application to toggle fullscreen every time you click on the menu item. So if you click once, it becomes fullscreen, if you click again, it becomes normal again. I tried the following but after I clicked it again, it wouldn't switch.

```
def Fullscreen(self):
        self.fullscreen = False
        if not self.fullscreen:
            self.root.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        else:
            self.root.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", False)
```

Comment: What makes you think your code is changing the status of full-screen to true?

Comment: It makes the app fullscreen but it won't switch back if I click on it again

Comment: Yes I know it wont switch back. Because you do not change the value of `self.fullscreen` after you make it fullscreen the GUI. You need to update your tracking variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a key part here. Nothing changes full screen back to True.

Here is a simple example of what you could do to toggle full screen.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(self, text="Toggle Fullscreen", command=self.fullscreen_toggle).pack()
        self.fullscreen = False

    def fullscreen_toggle(self):
        if self.fullscreen == False:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
            self.fullscreen = True
        else:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", False)
            self.fullscreen = False

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```